# Reproducible version of `git clone` to utilize docker build cache

Tags: git, docker, dvc

I try to automate the process of checking out a git repository and building a docker image based on the Dockerfile and the files in the repo. Inside the image, I want to use DVC. Assume something like

```
git clone ssh://git@example.com/my-super-great-repo.git
cd my-super-great-repo
docker build -t my-super-great-repo .
cd ..
rm -rf my-super-great-repo
```

and a Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:11-slim

WORKDIR /project
COPY . /project
CMD dvc pull 
...
```

The problem arises when I run the clone and build twice without changes to the repo. The `.git` directories are not identical, which means, the docker context is not identical, and therefore docker does not reuse the cache. This increases the build time, the storage requirements, and the image pull times (clients cannot reuse cached image layers when the repo changes).

I came up with the following ideas, but non of them is ideal

- Remove the `.git` directory altogether. This seems like the cleanest idea and in most cases this is the right thing to do. In my case, the images are part of a data pipeline and when a container is started, I want to pull datasets with [DVC](http://dvc.org). However, DVC needs to be launched in a git repository.
- I found out that only `.git/index` and `.git/logs/**` differ between checkouts. When I delete these files, DVC still works. However, using the mutilated repository is probably a very bad idea.

Is there another way to make the git repository identical between clones to add it to the image without voiding the caching mechanism?

Comment: Have you heard of `.dockerignore`?

Comment: I think both the index and the logs directory can be deleted with little bad effect. The index can be recreated with `git reset` and the `logs` directory is only (AFAIK) used for `git reflog` which is rarely needed in non-interactive use cases.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't see how `.dockerignore` could help in this situation. It limits the set of files considered as the docker context. In this case, adding files to `.dockerignore` would be equivalent to deleting them with the effect they are missing in the image?

Comment: `It limits the set of files considered as the docker context. In this case, adding files to .dockerignore would be equivalent to deleting them with the effect they are missing in the image?` Yes.

Comment: [Convincing DVC to work without the .git directory](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/3474) might work for me, but does not really answer the question.